# Convert a class into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a *DisplayedData* class ...

```
  public class DisplayedData
  {
    private int _key;
    private String _username;
    private String _fullName;
    private string _activated;
    private string _suspended;


    public int key { get { return _key; } set { _key = value; } }
    public string username { get { return _username; } set { _username = value; } }
    public string fullname { get { return _fullName; } set { _fullName = value; } }
    public string activated { get { return _activated; } set { _activated = value; } }
    public string suspended { get { return _suspended; } set { _suspended = value; } }
  }
```

And I want to to put the objects from this class into an array where all objects inside of this class should be converted into an String[]

I have..

```
DisplayedData _user = new DisplayedData();
String[] _chosenUser = _user. /* Im stuck here :)
```

or can I create an array where all the items inside are consist of variables of  different datatype so that the integer remains an integer and so the strings too?

Comment: Need more information to offer a good answer.  There are many answers to what you have here...  Are you trying to collect a list of users? Why a String[]?

Comment: Do you want to copy each property into the string array ? What do you mean when you say "where all objects inside of this class should be converted into an String[]" you only have ints and strings within the class, doesnt make sense to convert them to a string[], but you might want to copy to string[].

Comment: I want to copy all the public ints and strings of this class into an array

Comment: Can you explain why you want the data in an array and where you are using it?

Comment: Im going to put the array into a session variable and cast it to an array again in the other page. I chose to use an array because the DisplayedData class is not accessible in the other page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create an array "with your own hands" (see [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)):

```
String[] _chosenUser = new string[] 
{ 
    _user.key.ToString(), 
    _user.fullname,
    _user.username,
    _user.activated,
    _user.suspended
};
```

Or you could use [Reflection (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
_chosenUser = _user.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Select(p =>
                        {
                            object value = p.GetValue(_user, null);
                            return value == null ? null : value.ToString();
                        })
                    .ToArray();
```