# Create a manual property binder in c#

Tags: c#, .net, model-binding

I have a task I am trying to complete, and trying to do it the best way possible.

Let say I have a `jObject`

```
var jobj = {val1: 1, val2: "s"} // on server
```

and I need to user the properties in that object as the params for a `Method.Invoke` call.

```
someMethod.Invoke(class, params);
```

I need some way to take the properties from the `JObject` and convert them into an array of objects to pass to the invoke method.

I can easily get the param details

```
var param = Method.GetParameter("ParameterName");
```

this will give me the value, type be it a string or a complex object.

While a believe I could write the code to do this I think it would be better to use built in .Net functionality if it exists.

.Net does very similar conversions for all `WEB_API` and `MVC` Controller calls, and I would like to tap into those existing functions to do the work as they are probably very well vetted, but I am having trouble finding out how it is done.

I have found the `IActionValueBinder` and the `DefaultModelBinder` but I cannot figure out how to use these outside the context of a standard controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944816/convert-a-class-into-an-array

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that isnt what I was looking for.  I was looking for a parameter binding function that already exists in .Net, like the one that is used behind the scenes for Web API