# Type does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties'

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I am migrating a library project to a .net standard and I am getting the following compilation error when I try to use the `System.Reflection` API to call `Type:GetProperties()`:

> Type does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties'

Here it is my `project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of writing this, `GetProperties()` is now:

`typeof(Object).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;`

Comment: `DeclaredProperties` only returns properties declared on the type itself, excluding those inherited from parents

Answer (score 13):

**Update**: with .NET COre 2.0 release the `System.Type`  come back and so both options are available:

- `typeof(Object).GetType().GetProperties()`
- `typeof(Object).GetTypeInfo().GetProperties()`

  This one requires adding `using System.Reflection;`
- `typeof(Object).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties`

  Notice that this property returns `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>`, not `PropertyInfo[]` as previous two methods.

---

Most reflection-related members on `System.Type` are now on `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`.

First call `GetTypeInfo` to get a `TypeInfo` instance from a `Type`:

```
typeof(Object).GetTypeInfo().GetProperties();
```

Also, don't forget to use `using System.Reflection;`

Comment: That's right. But I think you have a typo in your answer. It is `typeof(Object).GetTypeInfo().GetProperties();`