# Parse string attributes of class into string array

Tags: c#, json

I am getting a server response that is parsed into an Object of the following class:

```
class IIOResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("b_code")]
    public string Bcode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("b_name")]
    public string Bname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("c_code")]
    public string Ccode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("supported_connections")]
    public List<SupportedConnection> SupportedConnections { get; set; }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to get the string attributes into an Array of strings. I know that I can get the count of the properties by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161175/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-attributes-that-an-object-has).

My Goal is to build a method that extracts the string attribute values of an object of any class into an array of strings.

Comment: please provide expected input and output.

Comment: What do you mean "string attributes".  If you want to get the Attributes on the properties, and read the properties of the attributed (like "b_code"), then use Reflection and GetCustomAttributes.  If you want to walk through the properties of a class instance and read all the values of the string-typed properties, use Reflection, GetProperties and GetGetter (I think that's the name) to build a collection of MethodInfos for the class.  Then, for an instance, use that collection to read the property values for that instance

Comment: I want to walk through the properties of a clas instance and read the values. That's it thanks Flydog.